# Center content in a div set to overflow, as content is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, coffeescript

I'm building a baseball simulator, and I have a "Game Report" div that records various game updates(represented in the bottom box in this image):
[image: baseball gameplay image]

As of now I have some JS that allows the div to scroll as new content is appended, but the new content is at the bottom.

I would like to center it vertically, as its generating, with white space below it ready for new content. As content is generated, it animates the content up, keeping the white space more or less constant.

I'm currently using this to auto-scroll it(coffeescript):

```
@reporter = $("#gameplay-game-report")
@height = $("#gameplay-game-report").height()
@reporter.animate({scrollTop: @height}, "slow")
@height += @reporter.height()
console.log("IN GAMEPLAY::addGameReport -> @height = #{@height}")
```

I tried playing around with adding and subtracting values from `@height` but that didn't result in any change I could observe.

Comment: So you want the very last element to be in the middle of this div, with white space below for the next element?

Comment: @JustinM yes, that's correct.

Comment: Ok then what I imagine is happening is it won't scroll the content any further because its at the bottom of the content. What you will need to do is to extend the actual height of the content. Either by adding padding to the bottom. Or by explicitly setting the height. Give me some time and I can set up a JsFiddle example to set the padding.

Answer (score 0):

As promised here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MLkkZ/1/) showing how this could be accomplished.
The key here is using

```
var height = $('#scrollable')[0].scrollHeight;
```

To get the height of the div you are scrolling.
Followed by

```
    padding-bottom: 200px;
```

To force the extra white space.

A side note on the padding I found If I set the div's height to 400 and the padding to 200 it will actually force the div to be 600. So set the div's height to half of the space you want and set the padding-bottom to the same.